# Promise function giving 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token }'

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

I'm attempting to deploy my code to Parse, and I keep getting an error stating:

`Update failed with Could not load triggers.  The error was Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in main.js:454`

Of the code below, line 454 that it refers to is this one:

```
      }, function(err) {
```

Full code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("MatchCenterTest", function(request, response) {
    //defines which parse class to iterate through
    var matchCenterItem = Parse.Object.extend("matchCenterItem");
    var query = new Parse.Query(matchCenterItem);
    var promises = [];
    //setting the limit of items at 10 for now
    query.limit(10);
    query.find().then(function(results) {
        for (i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
            url = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';
            //push function containing criteria for every matchCenterItem into promises array
              promises.push(function() {
                return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                  url: url,
                  params: {
                      'OPERATION-NAME' : 'findItemsByKeywords',
                      'SERVICE-VERSION' : '1.12.0',
                      'SECURITY-APPNAME' : '*APP ID GOES HERE*',
                      'GLOBAL-ID' : 'EBAY-US',
                      'RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT' : 'JSON',
                      'REST-PAYLOAD&sortOrder' : 'BestMatch',
                      'paginationInput.entriesPerPage' : '3',
                      'outputSelector=AspectHistogram&itemFilter(0).name=Condition&itemFilter(0).value(0)' : results[i].get('itemCondition'),
                      'itemFilter(1).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(1).value' : results[i].get('maxPrice'),
                      'itemFilter(1).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(1).paramValue' : 'USD',
                      'itemFilter(2).name=MinPrice&itemFilter(2).value' : results[i].get('minPrice'),
                      'itemFilter(2).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(2).paramValue' : 'USD',
                      //'itemFilter(3).name=LocatedIn&itemFilter(3).Value' : request.params.itemLocation,
                      'itemFilter(3).name=ListingType&itemFilter(3).value' : 'FixedPrice',
                      'keywords' : results[i].get('searchTerm'),
                  }
                });
              });
        }






          Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function(){

            var ebayPingResults = [];

            forEach(function(httpResponse) {
              var httpResponse = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);

              ebayPingResults.push(httpResponse);

            });

            response.success(
              console.log(ebayPingResults[0]); // So you can see what the response looks like for each httpRequest that was made  
            )

          }, function(err) {
                    console.log('error!');
                    response.error('DAMN IT MAN');
             });
    });
});
```

As far as I know, that bracket belongs there. Why is this error occurring?

Comment: This isn't plain javascript `forEach(function(httpResponse) {`.  Is there some library that makes that work?

Comment: When you've fixed the immediate issue, there's still some pretty fundamental things to fix in this code. eg. (1) `promises.push(function() {...})` will give you an array of functions, not an array of promises - I expect you want `promises.push(Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({...})`. (2) `forEach()` is an Array method, eg `myArray.forEach(fn)`. I expect that understanding and mastering the `request` and `response` objects is key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cloud code functions, the code must call either `response.success()` or `response.error()`. Each of these take an optional value that will be JSON encoded and returned to the calling code.

Your current code is calling `console.log()` in an entirely wrong place, and breaking the code.

Returning an anon function is also incorrect.

If you want to return the array of ping results, just use the following:

```
response.success(ebayPingResults);
```

If you want to log something, do it before your `response.success()` call:

```
console.log(ebayPingResults[0]);
response.success(ebayPingResults);
```

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code looks terribly wrong:

```
response.success(
              console.log(ebayPingResults[0]); // So you can see what the response looks like for each httpRequest that was made  
            )
```

seems like it must be

```
response.success(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Seems to fix the syntax issue, but it now says `success/error was not called`. Any idea why?

Comment: @Ghobs: what "it" says it?

Comment: The Parse logs when I attempt to call the function from my iOS app.

Comment: @Ghobs: I'm not sure how this question is relevant to iOS programming.

Comment: What you see above is Parse cloud code that is called from my iOS app, and then returns a response to the app.

Comment: If it's returned by parse.com then it makes sense to go through their documentation